# $q-1$ dimensional irreducible representations of ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

It is known that ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ has $q-1$ dimensional irreducible representations, say $\rho_i$, and they are $\frac{q(q-1)}{2}$. The subgroup ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ has index $q-1$ in ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

**Question 1.** Is some $\rho_i$ a representation induced from one dimensional representation of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$?

It looks to me rare, since (Except few cases) only trivial representation is the one dimensional representation of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q).$ But then this raises the following questions on subgroup of index $q-1$.

**Question 2.** In ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$, is the subgroup ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ only subgroup of index $q-1$?

Comment: Since $SL_n$ is almost always perfect, you are right that it is rare for those characters to be induced.

Comment: With a few exceptions for $q \le 11$, the largest proper subgroup of ${\rm SL}_2(q)$ has index $q+1$ (it is $q$ in each of the exceptional cases except $q=9$ when it is $6$), so any subgroup of index $q-1$ in ${\rm GL}_2(q)$ must contain and hence be equal to ${\rm SL}_2(q)$.